# Why is my script missing the first record of a recordset?

Tags: php, odbc, record, missing-data

I got a small PHP script retrieving value from a database. It works but it is just missing the very first record of the recordset.

Here is the code :

```
$conn = odbc_connect("database","user","passwd");

if (!$conn) {
   echo $php_errormsg;
   die("Connection failed");
}

$sql = "EXEC dbo.pr_stored_procedure param1, param2";

echo ("sql=". $sql."\n");
$rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);


while(odbc_fetch_row($rs)) {
   $item1 = odbc_result($rs,"item1");
   $item2 = odbc_result($rs,"item2"); 
   echo($item1 . " " .  $item2);
}

odbc_close($conn);
```

I don't understand why it would skip the first row  as this is very basic.

Comment: Daft question but are you certain the stored procedure you are calling works as expected?

Comment: yes because when doing the same with ASP classic, it works...all value get retrieved

Comment: Maybe try using `odbc_fetch_row($rs, 1);` before the while loop to make sure the first record is selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be bug in the ODBC driver or other library you use.

Do you have problems with similar queries executed in that environment or when you change params to return different dataset?

You have written the this query works from ASP, but also try to execute it in other ODBC environment. My favorite is ActivePython with `odbc` module or Jython with JDBC-ODBC bridge. You will find examples of such code in my question: [How to get trailing spaces from varchar column in Informix using ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464567/how-to-get-trailing-spaces-from-varchar-column-in-informix-using-odbc)

Maybe there is something special with first row? Example: I have seen Informix ODBC driver for Linux that returned empty data for first row if first column was datetime.

As soon as you see this query working in other ODBC environment try to enable ODBC tracing and compare trace from working environment with trace from PHP.